# OpenSSH - jump host on HP NA is not working

Tags: ubuntu, openssh

I would like to ask you if someone of you have similar problem to establish remote SSH connection via HPNA bastion host.

What I achieved so far is the notification on debug mode:
debug1: channel 0: new [stdio-forward]
debug1: getpeername failed: Bad file descriptor
debug1: Entering interactive session.
debug1: pledge: network
channel 0: open failed: administratively prohibited: User does not have permission
stdio forwarding failed
ssh_exchange_identification: Connection closed by remote host

I can authenticate to HPNA bastion host but from some reason is not possible to go further via jump host to destination host.

---

Here is the full output of the connection to remote device. For secure reason I've changed IP address of HPNA and destination_host.

```
OpenSSH_7.6p1 Ubuntu-4ubuntu0.3, OpenSSL 1.0.2n  7 Dec 2017
debug1: Reading configuration data /home/lab/.ssh/config
debug1: /home/lab/.ssh/config line 12: Applying options for SRX
debug1: Reading configuration data /etc/ssh/ssh_config
debug1: /etc/ssh/ssh_config line 19: Applying options for *
debug1: Setting implicit ProxyCommand from ProxyJump: ssh -vvv -W '[%h]:%p' my_HPNA_IP
debug1: Executing proxy command: exec ssh -vvv -W '[my_dest_host]:22' my_HPNA_IP
debug1: permanently_drop_suid: 1000
debug1: identity file /home/lab/.ssh/id_rsa type 0
debug1: key_load_public: No such file or directory
debug1: identity file /home/lab/.ssh/id_rsa-cert type -1
debug1: key_load_public: No such file or directory
debug1: identity file /home/lab/.ssh/id_dsa type -1
debug1: key_load_public: No such file or directory
debug1: identity file /home/lab/.ssh/id_dsa-cert type -1
debug1: key_load_public: No such file or directory
debug1: identity file /home/lab/.ssh/id_ecdsa type -1
debug1: key_load_public: No such file or directory
debug1: identity file /home/lab/.ssh/id_ecdsa-cert type -1
debug1: key_load_public: No such file or directory
debug1: identity file /home/lab/.ssh/id_ed25519 type -1
debug1: key_load_public: No such file or directory
debug1: identity file /home/lab/.ssh/id_ed25519-cert type -1
debug1: Local version string SSH-2.0-OpenSSH_7.6p1 Ubuntu-4ubuntu0.3
OpenSSH_7.6p1 Ubuntu-4ubuntu0.3, OpenSSL 1.0.2n  7 Dec 2017
debug1: Reading configuration data /home/lab/.ssh/config
debug1: /home/lab/.ssh/config line 2: Applying options for my_HPNA_IP
debug1: Reading configuration data /etc/ssh/ssh_config
debug1: /etc/ssh/ssh_config line 19: Applying options for *
debug2: resolving "my_HPNA_IP" port 8022
debug2: ssh_connect_direct: needpriv 0
debug1: Connecting to my_HPNA_IP [my_HPNA_IP] port 8022.
debug1: Connection established.
debug1: identity file /home/lab/.ssh/id_rsa type 0
debug1: key_load_public: No such file or directory
debug1: identity file /home/lab/.ssh/id_rsa-cert type -1
debug1: Local version string SSH-2.0-OpenSSH_7.6p1 Ubuntu-4ubuntu0.3
debug1: Remote protocol version 2.0, remote software version NA_2018.11.P01
debug1: no match: NA_2018.11.P01
debug2: fd 3 setting O_NONBLOCK
debug1: Authenticating to my_HPNA_IP:8022 as 'A635653'
debug3: put_host_port: [my_HPNA_IP]:8022
debug3: hostkeys_foreach: reading file "/home/lab/.ssh/known_hosts"
debug3: record_hostkey: found key type ECDSA in file /home/lab/.ssh/known_hosts:4
debug3: load_hostkeys: loaded 1 keys from [my_HPNA_IP]:8022
debug3: order_hostkeyalgs: prefer hostkeyalgs: ecdsa-sha2-nistp256-cert-v01@openssh.com,ecdsa-sha2-nistp384-cert-v01@openssh.com,ecdsa-sha2-nistp521-cert-v01@openssh.com,ecdsa-sha2-nistp256,ecdsa-sha2-nistp384,ecdsa-sha2-nistp521
debug3: send packet: type 20
debug1: SSH2_MSG_KEXINIT sent
debug3: receive packet: type 20
debug1: SSH2_MSG_KEXINIT received
debug2: local client KEXINIT proposal
debug2: KEX algorithms: curve25519-sha256,curve25519-sha256@libssh.org,ecdh-sha2-nistp256,ecdh-sha2-nistp384,ecdh-sha2-nistp521,diffie-hellman-group-exchange-sha256,diffie-hellman-group16-sha512,diffie-hellman-group18-sha512,diffie-hellman-group-exchange-sha1,diffie-hellman-group14-sha256,diffie-hellman-group14-sha1,ext-info-c
debug2: host key algorithms: ecdsa-sha2-nistp256-cert-v01@openssh.com,ecdsa-sha2-nistp384-cert-v01@openssh.com,ecdsa-sha2-nistp521-cert-v01@openssh.com,ecdsa-sha2-nistp256,ecdsa-sha2-nistp384,ecdsa-sha2-nistp521,ssh-ed25519-cert-v01@openssh.com,ssh-rsa-cert-v01@openssh.com,ssh-ed25519,rsa-sha2-512,rsa-sha2-256,ssh-rsa
debug2: ciphers ctos: chacha20-poly1305@openssh.com,aes128-ctr,aes192-ctr,aes256-ctr,aes128-gcm@openssh.com,aes256-gcm@openssh.com
debug2: ciphers stoc: chacha20-poly1305@openssh.com,aes128-ctr,aes192-ctr,aes256-ctr,aes128-gcm@openssh.com,aes256-gcm@openssh.com
debug2: MACs ctos: umac-64-etm@openssh.com,umac-128-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-256-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-512-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha1-etm@openssh.com,umac-64@openssh.com,umac-128@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-256,hmac-sha2-512,hmac-sha1
debug2: MACs stoc: umac-64-etm@openssh.com,umac-128-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-256-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-512-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha1-etm@openssh.com,umac-64@openssh.com,umac-128@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-256,hmac-sha2-512,hmac-sha1
debug2: compression ctos: none,zlib@openssh.com,zlib
debug2: compression stoc: none,zlib@openssh.com,zlib
debug2: languages ctos:
debug2: languages stoc:
debug2: first_kex_follows 0
debug2: reserved 0
debug2: peer server KEXINIT proposal
debug2: KEX algorithms: diffie-hellman-group-exchange-sha256,ecdh-sha2-nistp256,ecdh-sha2-nistp384,ecdh-sha2-nistp521
debug2: host key algorithms: ssh-dss,ssh-rsa,ecdsa-sha2-nistp256,ecdsa-sha2-nistp521,ecdsa-sha2-nistp384
debug2: ciphers ctos: aes128-ctr,aes192-ctr,aes256-ctr,3des-cbc,aes128-cbc,aes192-cbc,aes256-cbc
debug2: ciphers stoc: aes128-ctr,aes192-ctr,aes256-ctr,3des-cbc,aes128-cbc,aes192-cbc,aes256-cbc
debug2: MACs ctos: hmac-sha1,hmac-sha1-96,hmac-sha2-256
debug2: MACs stoc: hmac-sha1,hmac-sha1-96,hmac-sha2-256
debug2: compression ctos: none,zlib
debug2: compression stoc: none,zlib
debug2: languages ctos:
debug2: languages stoc:
debug2: first_kex_follows 0
debug2: reserved 0
debug1: kex: algorithm: ecdh-sha2-nistp256
debug1: kex: host key algorithm: ecdsa-sha2-nistp256
debug1: kex: server->client cipher: aes128-ctr MAC: hmac-sha2-256 compression: none
debug1: kex: client->server cipher: aes128-ctr MAC: hmac-sha2-256 compression: none
debug3: send packet: type 30
debug1: sending SSH2_MSG_KEX_ECDH_INIT
debug1: expecting SSH2_MSG_KEX_ECDH_REPLY
debug3: receive packet: type 31
debug1: Server host key: ecdsa-sha2-nistp256 SHA256:QmSAC50RHNQF1uJT1XDmAhAtc7gAObYgWFJGp+j5RSk
debug3: put_host_port: [my_HPNA_IP]:8022
debug3: put_host_port: [my_HPNA_IP]:8022
debug3: hostkeys_foreach: reading file "/home/lab/.ssh/known_hosts"
debug3: record_hostkey: found key type ECDSA in file /home/lab/.ssh/known_hosts:4
debug3: load_hostkeys: loaded 1 keys from [my_HPNA_IP]:8022
debug3: hostkeys_foreach: reading file "/home/lab/.ssh/known_hosts"
debug3: record_hostkey: found key type ECDSA in file /home/lab/.ssh/known_hosts:4
debug3: load_hostkeys: loaded 1 keys from [my_HPNA_IP]:8022
debug1: Host '[my_HPNA_IP]:8022' is known and matches the ECDSA host key.
debug1: Found key in /home/lab/.ssh/known_hosts:4
debug3: send packet: type 21
debug2: set_newkeys: mode 1
debug1: rekey after 4294967296 blocks
debug1: SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS sent
debug1: expecting SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS
debug3: receive packet: type 21
debug1: SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS received
debug2: set_newkeys: mode 0
debug1: rekey after 4294967296 blocks
debug2: key: /home/lab/.ssh/id_rsa (0x7fffe79c65b0), explicit
debug3: send packet: type 5
debug3: receive packet: type 6
debug2: service_accept: ssh-userauth
debug1: SSH2_MSG_SERVICE_ACCEPT received
debug3: send packet: type 50
debug3: receive packet: type 51
debug1: Authentications that can continue: password,keyboard-interactive
debug3: start over, passed a different list password,keyboard-interactive
debug3: preferred gssapi-keyex,gssapi-with-mic,publickey,keyboard-interactive,password
debug3: authmethod_lookup keyboard-interactive
debug3: remaining preferred: password
debug3: authmethod_is_enabled keyboard-interactive
debug1: Next authentication method: keyboard-interactive
debug2: userauth_kbdint
debug3: send packet: type 50
debug2: we sent a keyboard-interactive packet, wait for reply
debug3: receive packet: type 60
debug2: input_userauth_info_req
Password
Enter A635653's password:
debug2: input_userauth_info_req: num_prompts 1
Password:
debug3: send packet: type 61
debug3: receive packet: type 52
debug1: Authentication succeeded (keyboard-interactive).
Authenticated to my_HPNA_IP ([my_HPNA_IP]:8022).
debug3: ssh_init_stdio_forwarding: my_dest_host:22
debug1: channel_connect_stdio_fwd my_dest_host:22
debug1: channel 0: new [stdio-forward]
debug2: fd 4 setting O_NONBLOCK
debug2: fd 5 setting O_NONBLOCK
debug1: getpeername failed: Bad file descriptor
debug3: send packet: type 90
debug2: fd 3 setting TCP_NODELAY
debug3: ssh_packet_set_tos: set IP_TOS 0x10
debug1: Entering interactive session.
debug1: pledge: network
debug3: receive packet: type 92
channel 0: open failed: administratively prohibited: User does not have permission
debug2: channel_input_open_failure: channel 0: callback start
stdio forwarding failed
ssh_exchange_identification: Connection closed by remote host
```

Comment: could you add the output of `ssh -vvv ... (rest of original command)` to give more information?  Also: can you ssh from the bastion host to the destination host directly?  btw: I added some spaces before your output so that it is easier to read.

Comment: I will attach original output in separate answer as it is too long. When it comes about ssh from bastion host I can only establish remote session with parameter -l
like this below:
NA>ssh dest_host -l
Attempting to connect to device my_HostName (my_dest_host_ip).

Comment: I tried ssh from bastion host without -l parameter and it also works.

NA>ssh 1.1.1.1
Attempting to connect to device HOSTNAME (1.1.1.1).

Device SSH Login:  A635653
Device SSH Password:
--- JUNOS 18.4R2.7 built 2019-06-27 08:41:44 UTC